# Dúvida em Arrays - Iniciante

Tags: java, array

Como faço para que o método `mostraEmpregados` imprima na tela o nome dos funcionários que eu já adicionei?

Como construir a array dentro da própria declaração da classe Empresa, fazendo com que toda vez que uma `Empresa` é instanciada, a array de `Funcionario` que ela necessita também é criada?

```
package meu.programa;

public class Funcionario {
    String nome;
    String departamento;
    double salario;
    Data dataDeEntrada;
    String rg;
    boolean estaNaEmpresa = true;

    void recebeAumento(double valorDoAumento) {
        salario += valorDoAumento;
        System.out.println("O salario atual do funcionario " + this.nome + " eh: " + this.salario);
    }
    void calculaGanhoAnual () {
        double ganho = salario * 12;
        System.out.println("O ganho anual do funcionario " + this.nome + " eh: " + ganho);
    }
    void demite () {
        if (this.estaNaEmpresa == true) {
            this.estaNaEmpresa = false;
            System.out.println("O funcionario " + this.nome + " foi demitido ...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("O funcionario ja foi demitido ...");
        }
    }
    void mostra () {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("Departamento: " + this.departamento);
        System.out.println("Salario: " + this.salario);
        System.out.println("Data de entrada na empresa: " + this.dataDeEntrada.dataFormatada());
        System.out.println("RG: " + this.rg);
        System.out.println("É funcionario da empresa: " + this.estaNaEmpresa);

    }
}
```

.

```
class Empresa {
    String nome;
    String cnpj;
    Funcionario[] empregados;

    void adiciona(Funcionario f) {
        int contador = 0;
        this.empregados[contador] = f;
        contador++;
        if(contador == this.empregados.length) {
            System.out.println("A array está cheio ...");
        }

    }

    void criaArray (int n) {
        this.empregados = new Funcionario [n];

    }
    void mostraEmpregados() {
        for (int i=0; i <= this.empregados.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Funcionario na pos.: " + i);
            System.out.println(" Nome:" + this.nome);
        }
    }
}
```

E outra classe para testar a classe Empresa:

```
package meu.programa;

public class TestaEmpresa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        empresa.criaArray(5);

        Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();
        f1.nome = "Victor";

        Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario();
        f2.nome = "Guilherme";

        empresa.adiciona(f1);
        empresa.adiciona(f2);

        empresa.mostraEmpregados();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso é algum exercício, ou é para se usar na prática?

Se for exercício, o seu problema é que quando se cria um array em `empresa.criaArray(5)` ele vai criar um array com 5 posições, todas elas preenchidas com `null`. Desse modo, você pode descobrir se há "espaço" no array testando se cada um desses elementos é `null`. O primeiro `null` que você encontrar, use esse índice para armazenar seu `Funcionario`. Se você percorrer o array inteiro e não encontrar nenhuma posição com `null`, é porque o array está cheio (aí você vê o que é melhor fazer - lançar uma exceção, criar um novo array...)

Da mesma forma, seu `mostraEmpregados` está percorrendo o array inteiro, por isso ele vai dar problema se encontrar elementos nulos. Sugiro testar cada um deles antes de tentar imprimir.

Agora, se for pra usar na prática, o ideal mesmo é usar `java.util.ArrayList` (ou algo similar, como apontado na resposta do carlosfigueira).

Comment: É só um exercício mesmo. Obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

O local para inicializar o array de funcionários seria no *construtor* da classe Empresa, que é chamado toda vez que um objeto dessa classe é criado:

```
class Empresa {
    // ...
    public Empresa(int numeroDeEmpregados) {
        this.empregados = new Funcionario[numeroDeEmpregados];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Agora, essa solução é um pouco restrita - quando a empresa é criada você precisa saber o número de empregados, mas isso não é comum. Além do mais, uma empresa pode ter um número variável de empregados (demitidos / contratados), então o array não é a estrutura de dados mais apropriada para isso - arrays em java tem tamanho fixo. Uma sugestão é usar um `List` (por exemplo, `ArrayList`) que pode crescer dinamicamente dependendo da necessidade.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i <= this.empregados.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Funcionario na pos.: " + i);
    System.out.println(" Nome:" + this.nome);
}
```

@Victor, o `this` que você utiliza na linha 3 do método de visualização, se refere a instância da própria classe, ou seja, a referencia vai printar o nome da empresa, enquanto, acredito, que o que você espera é o nome do funcionário. A correção seria `System.out.println(" Nome:" + empregados[i].nome);` pois assim referencia a instancia correta de Funcionario que está contida no vetor, atráves do contador do for.

Acredito que isso funcionaria!

Coloquei o seu codigo para funcionar aqui, e retornou o que eu esperava mesmo... Ele imprime `Funcionario na pos.: i Nome: Nome dado à empresa`. Depois disto percebi que o seu for do método mostraEmpregados está um pouco equivado. Perceba, o valor do length, ou até mesmo da função `length()`, caso sejam `List`s, retorna a # de elementos da array, entretanto, os vetores em geral, tratam a posição do seu elemento a partir da posição 0. Então, se o array conter 1 elemento, ele terá `length` = 1, e posição = 0. Como vc colocou no método, daria um ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, já que ele tentaria `empregados[5]` onde 5 é a length do vetor, enquanto o vetor só conseguiria ir até 4, já que teria os valores de 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4.
Então o certo seria colocar `<` no lugar de `<=`.

No mais é isso. Como sei que é um exercício, sei que vc chegará a utilizar `Lists` então, não tenha pressa. Eu aconselharia, como o pessoal acima falou, inicializar o tamanho do vetor no próprio construtor, ficaria mais coerente, ao invés de chamar um método que zeraria o vetor e colocaria um novo vetor limpo no local, perdendo os valores anteriores... Tái, seria legal vc fazer com que esse método de `criaArray` fosse um `expandeArray` criando um novo array, e copiando os valores antigos para o novo! Seria legal também se o `mostraEmpregados()` chamasse direto o `mostra()` da classe empregado, pois assim vc teria as informações completas dos funcionarios.